# Weird action for MySQL IN / LIKE / EQUALS function

Tags: mysql

Before start: sorry for description too long. I've been confused by this question, and I'm not good at MySQL or SQL, hope for that you guys helps me figure this question out, BIG THANKS.

---

### Data Structure And Data Set

First, I need simplified my data as following description.

`Table A` with data structure

```
CREATE TABLE A (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO A VALUSE(1);
INSERT INTO A VALUSE(2);
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

`Table B` with data structure

```
CREATE TABLE B (id INT PRIMARY KEY, json_config TEXT);
INSERT INTO B VALUSE(1, '{"id":"1"}');
INSERT INTO B VALUSE(2, '{"id":"2"}');
```

| id | json_config |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"id":"1"} |
| 2 | {"id":"2"} |

---

### Operation And Question

Then I want to find data from `A` and `B`, where `A's id` equals `B's json_config` id, and `B's id` in (`1`, `2`).

```
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id IN ('1', '2')
```

and it works

| a.id | b.json_config | b.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"id":"1"} | 1 |
| 2 | {"id":"2"} | 2 |

Then I tried same things, but this time `A's id` in only (`1`)

```
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id IN ('1')
```

`IT RETURNS NOTHING !!!` and same result happens on following script

```
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id IN (1);
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id = 1;
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id = '1';
```

But following script works

```
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id like 1;
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id like '1';
```

returns

| a.id | b.json_config | b.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"id":"1"} | 1 |

by the work 'not' operator works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id NOT IN (1);
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id <> 1;
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id NOT LIKE 1;
```

| a.id | b.json_config | b.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | {"id":"2"} | 2 |

So, first question comes out

**Why operator `IN` and `=`/`EQUALS` not work, but `LIKE` works ?**

---

Then I thought, why not should all the equation's result, to find out which one returns false. So I wrote following script.

```
SELECT *, 
    (json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id')) as json_id, 
    (a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id')) as config_equals, 
    (b.id IN ('1', '2')) as id_in 
FROM a, b 
WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id IN ('1', '2')
```

and the result surprises me.

| a.id | b.json_config | b.id | json_id | config_equals | id_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"id":"1"} | 1 | "1" | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | {"id":"2"} | 2 | "2" | 0 | 1 |

My second question comes out

**How MySQL returns result when the first judgement always false?**

---

by the way, i wondering does first question about `IN` evaluated as false? I wrote following script.

```
SELECT *, 
    (json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id')) as json_id, 
    (a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id')) as config_equals, 
    (b.id IN ('1')) as id_in 
FROM a, b 
WHERE a.id = json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AND b.id IN ('1', '2')
```

the answer is

| a.id | b.json_config | b.id | json_id | config_equals | id_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"id":"1"} | 1 | "1" | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | {"id":"2"} | 2 | "2" | 0 | 0 |

Third question comes out.

**If `IN` with single element returns `True` and it returns when first judge's value is `False`, WHY I can't just find any result first time?**

---

All of these things are too wired for me, hope someone can help me out.

Comment: *Data Structure And Data Set* Please provide it as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: You mix tablenames. You use `b.json_config` in the most first query whereas table `b` does not contain such column. Please make your question consistent.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. However, if you match the datatypes in the WHERE clause then it'll produce the expected result i.e. `SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = CAST(json_extract(b.json_config, '$.id') AS SIGNED) AND b.id IN (1)`. `json_extract` returns JSON datatype so comparison needs some kind of implicit type conversion which could be triggering the bug. IDK if this is an answer.